# to show $X$ is disconnected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I was asked in the exam to show $X=\{(p_1,\dots,p_n):p_i\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ is disconnected.

But  is this  a valid question as they did not mentioned  any mother space, anyway I assumed they asked me to show that $X$ is disconnected in $\mathbb{R}^n$

$\mathbb{Q}$ is disconnected in $\mathbb{R}$, here is one disconnection $$A_1=(-\infty,\sqrt{2})\cap \mathbb{Q}, A_2=(\sqrt{2},\infty)\cap\mathbb{Q}$$

Should I take $A_1\times A_2\dots\times A_n$ for showing disconnection of $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Thank you for discussion and help.

Comment: You don't need a concept of a "mother space" to define connectedness - it's all about finding two open subsets $A,B\subset X$ with $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $A\cup B=X$.

Comment: That's right, @akkkk, yet he then needs a *topology* defined on that set....

Comment: +1 both for showing your work and for assuming something *not trivial* in your exam. In my university there's a general rule: "You're making a mathematics exam? Then it is NOT supposed to be easy, let alone trivial. Don't cling from this or that little omission in some question to avoid giving a worthwhile answer...or else".

Comment: :) Thank you for the encouragement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quickest route is probably to note that projection onto the first coordinate is a continuous surjection onto the rationals. Thereby the space cannot be connected because it has a disconnected continuous image.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** for $n=2$ take $A_1\times \Bbb Q$ and $A_2\times\Bbb Q$.

Clearly, $X$ can be endowed with a discrete topology (which is often natural for countable spaces), but the disconnectedness is of course trivial. That's why I guess you're right assuming the inherited topology of $\Bbb R^n$

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the following useful:

**Claim:** A topological space $\,X\,$ is *disconnected* iff there exists a **continuous** surjective function $\,X\to\{0\,,\,1\}\,$ , where $\,\{0\,,\,1\}\subset\Bbb R\,$  gets the inherited euclidean topology (and, thus, it is a discrete space)

Well, in your case you could try

$$f:X\to\{0,1\}\;,\;\;f(p_1,\ldots,p_n):=\begin{cases}0& ,\;\;\;p_1\in A_1:=(-\infty\,,\,\sqrt 2)\cap\Bbb Q\\{}\\1& , \;\;\;p_1\in A_2:=(\sqrt 2\,,\,\infty)\cap\Bbb Q\end{cases}$$

Assuming, of course, the topology on $\,X\,$ is the inherited one from the euclidean one in $\,\Bbb R^n\,$

**==** For all those who did read this answer before and the comments below: I was wrong, Stefan was right and the answer now's corrected.

Comment: What is mapped to $0$?

Comment: Well @StefanH., that was a typo, *obviously*. Do you think that's reason enough to downvote?

Comment: I didn't know it was a typo. I assumed that one value should have been $0$, but the map is not continuous then.

Comment: The preimage of $0$ is $(0,...,0)$.

Comment: ...and I even determined the topogy of $\,\Bbb Q^n\,$ is the one inherited from $\,\Bbb R^n\,$ , *not* the discrete one...*sigh*...Ok, editing on its way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HINT,we conisider $n=2$. $ A=(-\infty,\sqrt2)\times (-\infty,\sqrt2)\cap\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb {Q}$ $=$$ (-\infty,\sqrt2]\times (-\infty,\sqrt2]\cap\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb {Q}$, from this we can say $A$ is clopen set.